# Creating Tag Synonyms for Computer Tag

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Again, working through some of the tag wikis. The [computer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) tag could easily have synonyms, such as PCM (Powertrain Control Module), ECM (Engine Control Module), PCU (Powertrain Control Unit), ECU (Engine Control Unit), and probably others. Would it be plausible/advisable to add these synonyms under the [computer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) tag? I now have the ability to create synonyms, but only if I have a score of 5+ within that tag, so am unable to do something this in this specific tagr. Also, tags for ECM/PCM/ECU/PCU do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what would be best. On one hand the current tag [computer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) is a catch all for all of those systems and since no one has created the other tags PCM, BCM, etc I'm not sure it's necessary. On the other there are so many computers in modern cars and all manufactures have there own acronyms I am not sure breaking them up into subset will be beneficial. But since no one has created those other tags I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As you know, I've been working on the tags ... just trying to figure out if we wanted the wiki excerpt to say, "Use this for PCM/ECM/PCU/ECU/etc" ... I mean, I get it, no doubt, but trying to make the wiki excerpt be appreciable to all.

Comment: @Paulster2 Overdue welcome to the site! It's good to see more professionals getting involved. I would recommend letting the tag wiki indicate it was a catch all.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks! As an aside, I'm having fun being here ... maybe a little too much fun ;-)